# Deploy app bundle without signing Windows

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

So, my team and I are developing an app but we don't have a code signing certificate for multiple reasons. We are using the Universal Windows blank app template, so the result is an .appxbundle. I thought I could deploy it like any other program, without a Code Signing Certificate, but I can't figure out how to do that, is it possible?

PS: using Universal Windows template for W10 on VS2017.

Thanks in advance and tell me if you don't understand,
RektibouCaribou

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but I don't see why you couldn't use a test certificate to deploy your app locally (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230260.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx). Or do you mean deploy to the Windows Store? In that case you will need a valid certificate.

Comment: Maybe use MakeAppx.exe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767(v=vs.85).aspx) and not sign the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have generated package file successfully.

> you can sideload apps to your device without submitting them to the Store. This lets you install them and test them out using the app package (.appx) that you have created. If you have an app that you don’t want to sell in the Store, like a line-of-business (LOB) app, you can sideload that app so that other users in your company can use it.

MSDN source:[Sideload your app package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-package)

Comment: I knew that, I was planning not to upload it to the store, but I wanted to know if (not for internal use) an appx could be installed on other PCs without a Code Signing Certificate

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do this. You would have to install certificate on the machine before installing your app. You could use [signtool.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx) to generate a certificate for internal use.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) Well, I guess we'll have to purchase one :/